# Customizing Asp.Net Identity User to store data in multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Our MVC 5 app is using Entity Framework with Code First. Our design calls for user data, including a hashed password to be stored in one table (Profile) while the email address used to login with will be stored in another table (ProfileIdentifier).

We would like to leverage as much of Asp.Net identity as possible. However, I am not sure how to customize it to use the multiple table structure we have.

I can create a SQL script to provide the data that the standard User object would have like this:

```
SELECT p.[ProfileId]                        AS Id -- GUID
      , pid.ProfileIdentifierValue          AS Email
      , pid.ConfirmedDate                   AS EmailConfirmed
      , LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL([Salutation] + ' ','') + 
        ISNULL([FirstName] + ' ','') + 
        ISNULL([MiddleName] + ' ','') + 
        ISNULL([LastName],'')))
            AS Name 
      ,[Password]                           AS PasswordHash
      ,[PasswordSalt]
      ,[SecurityQuestion]
      ,[SecurityAnswer]
      , pid.ProfileIdentifierValue          AS UserName
FROM [dbo].[Profile]                    AS p
    INNER JOIN dbo.ProfileIdentifier    AS pid
        ON p.ProfileId = pid.ProfileId
WHERE pid.ProfileIdentifierTypeId = 1
```

But how, in my C# code, do I map an IdentityUser object to this. Would I need to create a custom user object? A custom User manager and user store? I've played around with a bunch of code, and read several articles online, but can't seem to fit all of the pieces together. Am I not asking the right questions? Please help!

Comment: Stop right there and hash your password! http://plaintextoffenders.com/faq/devs

Comment: Oh yes, the password is of course hashed... :) Just for simplicity of the post I put it as you see it. But the code is more secure.